# MPC model used in Ligero and Limbo

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, multiparty-computation

Ligero (https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3133956.3134104) and Limbo (https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/215.pdf) use a somewhat unique MPC model for their zk-PCP where not all parties communicate with each other.

Briefly, in their model there is a sender $P_S$, $n$ servers $P_i, i \in [n]$ and a receiver $P_R$. The protocol begins by sampling some initial random coin $r_S$ and then sharing an initial message from $P_S$ to each of $P_i$. Then the protocol repeats for $\rho -1$ rounds, and for each round $j \in [2, \rho]$, basically the steps above is repeated: sample some random coin $r_j$, secret share a message from $P_S$ to each of $P_i$ and each $P_i$ do some local computation. I have two questions regarding this paradigm. Finally at the final round $P_i$ send their output to $P_R$ to be reconstructed. Notably the servers $P_i, i\in[n]$ do not send any messages except in the last round.

1. How does one do arbitrary computation in this model? Suppose you need to do a multiplication $[a] \cdot [b]$, what messages does $P_S$ send to the parties in $P_i$? How can't see how this works when parties cannot communicate with each other.
2. How is $\rho$ selected? Is this related to the number of gates?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in point 1. In then Ligero paper it is explained how to check for multiplications.  Mind that Ligero the objective is to check, not to compute.

Comment: For example in section 3.1 https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/215.pdf the authors define a standalone MPC model (the same one as I described in the question) and correctness is defined for this model. This is without getting into the zero-knowledge proofs or multiplication checks. So I'm wondering what it would look like if you compute a circuit in this model.